# pythone 3.3.2 age >= 24: TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int()

Tags: python

```
print("how old are you")
age = input(">")
if age >= 24:
print("you are getting old")
print (age)
else:
print("i don't care")
print (age)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
if age >= 24:
TypeError: unorderable types:     str() >= int()
```

Comment: In python 3.*
input is the equivalent of raw_input in python 2.7.*. This may have been what was confusing you.

Answer (score 8):

On Python 3, `input()` *always* returns a string value. Use the [`int()` type](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to convert it:

```
if int(age) >= 24:
```

A string value and an int are not orderable:

```
>>> '24' > 23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

Note that `int()` can throw a `ValueError` exception, if the input cannot be converted:

```
>>> int('Why do you want to know my age?')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Why do you want to know my age?'
```

Answer (score 3):

`age` is a string, not an int. To make it an int, use the `int()` function, so:

```
print("how old are you")
age = input(">")
if int(age) >= 24:
    print("you are getting old")
    print (age)
...
```

Note the line:

```
if int(age) >= 24:
```

Comment: thanks man really g8 didn't expect an answer that fast thanks again